# Trying to concatenate all my JS into one file and needing some JS framework/pattern type advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, frameworks

Just in case it matters, I use ASP.NET 3.5 with VB.NET.  I have nested MasterPages and UpdatePanels with Partial PostBacks.  I include Modernizr 1.7 with YepNopeJs/IE Shim in my head section.  Right before the closing body tag, I include my jQuery 1.6, jQuery UI 1.8.12, and this script.js I'm trying to build.

I'm thinking of using something like:

```
SITE = {

    PAGES     : { ... },
    VARS      : { ... },
    HELPERS   : { ... },
    PLUGINS   : { ... },

    init      : function() { ... }

};

SITE.init();
```

**UPDATE**

Ok with Levi's advice, I came up with this solution:

```
var SFAIC = {};                                   // Global namespace

SFAIC.common = { ... };                           // Shared properties
SFAIC.common.fn = { ... };                        // Shared functions
SFAIC.plugin = {

    qtip: $.fn.qtip,
    validate: $.fn.validate,
    validator: $.fn.validator

};
SFAIC.init = function() { ... };                  // Global initializer

$(document).ready(function() { SFAIC.init(); });
```

Then each page would have its own object literal like:

```
SFAIC.Main = {};                                  // Main.aspx 

SFAIC.Main.someSection = { ... };                 // Some Section's properties
SFAIC.Main.someSection.fn = { ... };              // Some Section's functions
SFAIC.Main.anotherSection = { ... };              // Another Section's properties
SFAIC.Main.anotherSection.fn = { ... };           // Another Section's functions
SFAIC.Main.init = function() { ... };             // Main.aspx's intializer

$(document).ready(function() { SFAIC.Main.init(); });
```

Comment: How big is the website in question?  That could be relevant to the answer.

Comment: That's kind of a trick question.  The website is small in terms of pages.  In terms of code-behind, it's huge.  In terms of client-side, it's anywhere from a couple hundred to upwards of a thousand lines of code per page.  I think though, that object literal is the way I WANT to go and is probably the most practical.  I just don't know exactly the best way of putting all the code into the object literal and executing based on the page.

Comment: Note that in jQuery `.fn` actually means `.prototype` it's a way to define methods on a jQuery object rather then a box to store functions. It may be misleading if your comparing it to `jQuery.fn`

Comment: Yea, I was confused about that.  I wanted a box to store my functions.  Is there something better or a way to mix prototype with object literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I recommend that you make a new object for section and a new function for each page/item.**
However, the more scripts you add in this way, the harder it gets to manage the whole in an editor.  Netbeans has a feature that lets you jump to parts of the object and helps manage this.

Example:

```
var lib = {}; // your library

//maybe you like the plural name plugins better. That's fine.
lib.plugin = {
    //define plugins here
};

//maybe you like the plural name helpers better. That's fine too.
lib.helper = {
    //define your helpers here
    cycle: function() {
        //code for the cycle plug-in
    }
};

lib.account = {
    //you could stick code that is general to all account pages here
};

lib.account.overview = function() {
    //you could stick code that is specific to the account overview page here
    //maybe you'd use the cycle plug-in to show their latest posts.
    lib.plugin.cycle();

};

lib.account = {
    //you could stick code that is general to all account pages here
};

lib.account.overview = function() {
    //you could stick code that is specific to the account overview page here
    //maybe you'd use the cycle plug-in to show their latest posts.

    lib.plugin.cycle();

};
```

Then on the Account Overview page you'd call `lib.account.overview()`.

Comment: Question.  Let's say I use the validation jQuery plugin and the qtip2 jQuery plugin.  Both attach themselves to the `$.fn` with `$.extend`.  Therefore, I could access them `$.fn.validate`, `$.fn.validator`, or `$.fn.qtip`. Would it be a best practice to create a `lib.plugin = { qtip: $.fn.qtip, validate: $.fn.validate, validator: $.fn.validator };` where I could use `lib.plugin.validator`, `lib.plugin.qtip`, etc. or should I not even worry about the lib.plugin object and use the `$.fn` route?

Comment: All that the `lib.*` entries would do is include them for that page.  You would proceed to use them like normal.  Also, you would want to use the unminified version of the scripts in the plug-in as they could possibly be reduced further by being included in the giant script.  I highly recommend that you have a good editor when using this method. Because it can get quite long.

Comment: I use VS2008 and soon we are making the move to VS2010.  I would consider it the best editor on the market. As far as my plugins.js for dev, I use the unminified versions of all my plugins.  I do have a plugins.min.js that have the packed or minified versions that I use in rc and production modes.  I guess my question is more of a preference, but was curious if people wrap the $.fn.xxx into a lib.plugin.xxx for readability or if they prefer to just use the $.fn.xxx.  I'm kind of an organizational neat freak when it comes to my code.  I often over-analyze these things I think.

Comment: Anything that lives on `$.fn.method` ... etc should not be called directly. you should call `$(selector).method`. You should avoid accessing or extending them directly.

Comment: Well, take for instance, the [qTip plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/).  Its defaults live at `$.fn.qtip.defaults`, so to modify them, Craig recommends `$.fn.qtip.defaults = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.qtip.defaults, { ... });`.  Or, if you have a need to modify a property that isn't exposed in the defaults, like zindex, you have to do `$.fn.qtip.zindex = getMaxZIndex();`.  I don't want to have to do `$("#tooltip").qtip.zindex = getMaxZIndex();` or `$("#tooltip").qtip({ ... my defaults here ... });` for every single call.  That's why you access directly and set the defaults once.

Answer (score 1):

**For Production:**

Use a package like closure, uglify or the one I mention at the end to package all your code into one file and send that.

**For Development:**

I would recommend for structure you use a asynchronous javascript loader like

[`require.js`](http://requirejs.org/).

This means you have lot's of modules and you specifically state the dependancies.

For example you would have one main.js

```
// main.js

require([
    "jquery.js",
    "jquery.ui.js", 
    ...
], function() {
    // if the correct location is "mysite.com/foo/" then url will be "foo"
    var url = window.location.pathname.match(/\/(\w+)\//)[1] || "mainpage";
    require(url + ".js", function(pageObj) {
        // ...
    });
});

// foo.js

define({
    pageStuff: ...
});
```

I recommend you read through the requireJS docs to understand their structuring system. It's one of the best I've found.

When it comes to optimising all javascript into one file you just use their [builder](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs). This should be part of your project deploy system.

Comment: This really doesn't do what I want though.  I already have my system created with a js file for each page where I have the ability through ContentPlaceHolders to include that page js file without the need of a loader.  If for whatever reason I wanted to go the loader route, I use Modernizr which utilizes YepNopJs, so I could just use that if I wanted to.  But, since I don't want to maintain all the different js files any longer and I want them all in one js file so that I have intellisense in Visual Studio, that's why I'm asking what I'm asking.

Comment: @Scott One gigantic file with all the data would be a nightmare for me. Having all my methods / functions set up like that in one big global object would encourage far too much hard coupling.

Comment: @Raynos - I'm just following the advice of Paul Irish and the like, that state that we need to concatenate js into one plugins.js file and one script.js file for cross-browser optimization's sake.

Comment: @Scott I agree with that. You just need to use an automated builder tool like the one I linked to do that. You don't write it all in one file.

Comment: @Raynos: I disagree with this method on several points, but I did ask for a scale for the website as if it's really large then the method I posted gets a bit hairy.  Each has their strengths and benefits.

Comment: @LeviMorrison what's wrong with modularizing all your code? The best part about modular code is _not a single global variable_

Comment: @Raynos and the best part about doing it my way is _that it is._    I'm not saying its the best way.  I'm just saying each way has benefits.

Comment: @LeviMorrison But what are those benefits. What are the several points you disagree on.

Comment: @Raynos You're really looking too hard into this.  With modularized structure, your codebase is split across multiple files and directories.  With the way I posted, they are modularized in ONE file.  That's the difference, essentially.  It's the same idea but implemented very differently.  We could pull apart other differences and benefits, no doubt.

Comment: @LeviMorrison I don't see why doing it one file is better though.

Comment: @Raynos which is precisely why you like your way.  It has the advantage of being in one place, it uses javascript that you already should know how to use, and it doesn't require a loader application.  I'll be honest and say that with large-scale projects it doesn't work as well.  It depends on your needs.

Comment: There is a learning curve to using something like `require`. But I wouldn't call having all your code in one (5k) line file an advantage.

Comment: Actually, the difference is that, Raynos, your way requires an auto-loader to load scripts, and based on the browser and how many files need to be loaded, could be costly, performance wise.  1 packed file will obviously load better/faster in terms of performance across browsers.  Not to mention, in terms of coding in Visual Studio, the intellisense will be there and you don't have to worry about adding `/// <reference path="/js/jquery-1.6.0.js" />` for intellisense.  I want to know what vars I have available to me, so I don't have to dig through files.  1 file + intellisense is plus for that.

Comment: @Raynos: You misunderstand.  The file you develop in is not minified, it's fully expanded and preferably loaded with comments.  You simply minify it for production.  And it would be a lot bigger than 5k anyway for lots of projects.

Comment: @Scott You use an automated tool to package your 50 javascript files into one big minifizied gzip file. For development purpose you have everything nicely set up in multiple files with a nice dependancy management and for production you send the client one big min.js.gzip file. @LeviMirrison I meant managing one big 5000+ line javascript file would be a pain.

Comment: @Raynos, I understand. I've understood the entire time. What I'm saying is that in Visual Studio, we have what's called Intellisense, which is code auto-completion.  When you code in multiple JS files, Intellisense breaks b/c it only knows what's been created in the file your in. However, as I said in my last comment, you can reference other files.  It's very flaky and you have to maintain another file, a documentation file, ending with a -vsdoc.js or -debug.js so that Visual Studio recognizes it and loads the documentation into the Intellisense. Hence why I want to eliminate this headache.

Comment: @Scott that's a valid choice to make. I don't use VS as my JS text editor so I don't have that issue. Instead I tend to use `vim`